# Past perfect in conditional type-2?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I bumped in a silly meme in facebook containing the following dialog (word for word):

> A: "If I had said I love you would you say it back?"

> B: "Of course!"

> A: "I love you."

> B: "It back."

To my understanding of the English grammar, the first sentence's construction belongs to a mixed conditional type and doesn't make sense in the context of the dialog. It seems to me that there should go type-2 conditional with simple past "if I said that I love you...".

However, some people claim that there is no mistake in the sentence and that it allegedly expresses an accomplished action "I have said" which transforms into "I had said" of the type-2 conditional.

I would love to see an answer from **native** speakers who could confirm my suspect that there is a grammatical mistake in that sentence or on the contrary disprove it.

Comment: There is no reason to include _had_ in the sentence; it's just careless writing.